# Why service does not have any active Endpoint when install grafana from helm to kubernetes-sigs/kind?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind - version 0.4.0
Create kubernetes from kubernetes-sigs/kind

```
kind create cluster
Creating cluster "kind" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.15.0)
```

kubectl create serviceaccount

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
serviceaccount/tiller created
```

kubectl create clusterrolebinding

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller-cluster-rule created
```

kubectl patch deploy

```
kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
deployment.extensions/tiller-deploy patched


helm init

helm install stable/nginx-ingress

helm install --name grafana stable/grafana --set=ingress.enabled=True,ingress.hosts={grafana.domain.com} --namespace demo --set rbac.create=true
```

kubectl logs loping-wallaby-nginx-ingress-controller-76d574f8b7-5m6n5

```
W0629 17:13:59.709497       6 controller.go:797] Service "demo/grafana" does not have any active Endpoint.
[29/Jun/2019:17:14:03 +0000]TCP200000.000
I0629 17:14:45.223234       6 status.go:295] updating Ingress demo/grafana status from [] to [{ }]
I0629 17:14:45.226343       6 event.go:209] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"demo", Name:"grafana", UID:"228cde81-cb97-4313-ad86-90a273b2206d", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1938", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress demo/grafana
```

kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE   NAME      HOSTS                ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
demo        grafana   grafana.domain.com             80      3m58s
```

kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -l app=grafana

```
NAMESPACE   NAME      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
default     grafana   ClusterIP   10.104.203.243   <none>        80/TCP    24m
```

kubectl get endpoints

```
NAME                                           ENDPOINTS                      AGE
grafana                                        10.244.0.10:3000               21m
kubernetes                                     172.17.0.2:6443                56m
loping-wallaby-nginx-ingress-controller        10.244.0.8:80,10.244.0.8:443   48m
loping-wallaby-nginx-ingress-default-backend   10.244.0.7:8080                48m
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few concerns about your current scenario:

1. You have to check installed [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) helm chart in order to find out why `grafana` service resides in separate namespace `default` and not in `demo` namespace as per helm deploy parameter `--namespace demo`.
2. Since you have not specified in `helm install` command `controller.service.type` parameter, [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) would be implemented with `LoadBalancer` type of relevant service, in this case Ingress Controller expects to receive external IP address using cloud provider’s load balancer and I assume that your current kubernetes provisioner [kubernetes-sigs/kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) is not a good choice to adopt outward access to the Kubernetes cluster. Therefore, I would suggest to use [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service for Nginx Ingress controller in order to expose 80 and 443 port on some specific port in the host machine.

   `helm install --name grafana stable/grafana --set=ingress.enabled=True,ingress.hosts={grafana.domain.com} --namespace demo --set rbac.create=true --controller.service.type=NodePort`
3. Issue that you mentioned is more like harmless and doesn't significantly affect the Nginx Ingress Controller's functionality, because it means that for some short period of time [Liveness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) probe for Grafana Pod has not been initiated and target enpoint has not been released during Grafana Helm chart deploy. You can even re-spawn Nginx Ingress controller Pod to justify my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

you are using type of service as "ClusterIp" , so you will not get external Ip address.
Change the Service type to "Loadbalancer" then you get Ip address which you can browse through internet.

Comment: op was asking about using the ingress controller as a load balancer, not the actual grafana service.